# How to speed up Ubuntu on a netbook

Tags: ubuntu, performance, netbook

How do I speed up the latest version of Ubuntu on a VIA C7-M 1.6 GHz based **netbook** (HP 2133)? For example, full screen videos are very slow in the default configuration.

Comment: What type of videos? If you're talking about high resolution videos (720p and higher) you're not going to get spectacular result, really.

Comment: Why was this down voted so much? Sure, not much information is provided, but it's still an acceptable question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Ubuntu Netbook Remix](http://www.ubuntu.com/GetUbuntu/download-netbook)? It is aimed at running better on netbooks.

Or you could try out [XFCE](http://www.xfce.org/) (or xubuntu) or [LXDE](http://www.lxde.org/) as lighter-weight desktop environments.